# How to reset camera's matrixWorld on webXR

Tags: three.js, webxr

I use `camera.matrixWorld.decompose()` to get the current matrix of the AR camera like the following:

```
var position = new THREE.Vector3();
var quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
var scale = new THREE.Vector3();
camera.matrixWorld.decompose(position, quaternion, scale);
```

They are initialized to default (e.g. `{x:0, y:0, z:0}` for the position) when I press the AR Button. (https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/webxr/ARButton.js)

I wonder if it's possible to reset the matrix while the app is running without having to go back and repressing the AR button.

---

**More details:**
I would like to know if it's possible to reset the AR camera position to [0, 0, 0] as if restarting the AR session. For example, if I start the app while putting my phone on my desk, that position will be [0, 0, 0] and I can see a cube positioned at [0, 0, -3]. And if I move to my bed, I will no longer see the cube in front of me because it's still on my desk. If I restart the app, then I can see the cube on my bed since the default position [0, 0, 0] is on my bed. I wonder if it would be possible for a user to press a button to reset the position to [0, 0, 0] without having to restart the app.

Comment: I'm not sure your question is clear. When using `decompose()`, you actually convert the transformation stored in the matrix into three distinct properties. You are not "getting" the matrix.

Comment: @Mugen87 I'm sorry, I just added more details to my question. I hope it helps you understand my question better.